# The "net" tag is used for different purposes

Tags: discussion, tags

Just take a look at the questions tagged [net](/questions/tagged/net): Some users added the tag to network related questions; some users added the tag to questions about .Net.

[net](/questions/tagged/net) has two different semantics. How do you guys solve the problem in a case like this?

Comment: `net` should definitely be replaced with `.net` for dot net questions.  `net` is a horrible tag for network or networking related questions.  However, it is valid for some things.  One of which would be the net library in Perl.  Now, how best to clean that up?

Comment: @squillman - The things it is valid for are far less popular than the things it is abused for. Of the first 100 questions, 2 are about the Ruby library ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495034/ruby-url-parse-error), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495219/ruby-nethttp-start-issue)) and just [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343535/perl-netldap-filter-not-working) is about the Perl use. You don't want to volunteer to clean up after the people who don't know to use `.net` or `networking` if you're advocating to repurpose the tag for Perl. A tag wiki won't handle that abuse.

Comment: We should probably create a net-library tag, that can be used in conjunction with the Perl tag (and will allow it to be used if some other language has the same library).

Comment: @LanceRoberts I've originally noticed the problem because of this question that I replied. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635035/why-is-the-netmask-in-netip-set-wrong/7636149#7636149 - It's really about Perl Net library! Should I retag it to networking or just wait then?

Comment: @stivlo, I just added the `net-library` tag, and tagged it.  I'll throw it on a few others to make it stick.  Edit: Actually, there were only two other questions tagged [perl] and [net] so I fixed them both.

Comment: @LanceRoberts excellent, thanks

Comment: @LanceRoberts I've retagged a few questions. What about this one in Ruby? Should it be net-library or networking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495034/ruby-url-parse-error

Comment: @stivlo, looks like it, so I retagged it, but don't know much about Ruby, so someone else may need to throw their 2 cents in.

Comment: @LanceRoberts sorry for disturbing again, I've added the following description to the net tag: "Please don't use this tag for new questions: use .net or networking or net-library" http://stackoverflow.com/tags/net/info - waiting peer review

Comment: I retagged ~25 questions. most went to `.net` or `networking`, a few didn't need it at all, one went to some other `something-net` tag I forget what it was now (it was in the question and it already existed) -- so long as you're careful 2/3rds+ of the questions are obviously `.net` or `networking`

Comment: @LanceRoberts - [only 1 net question surviving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/net), since I can't edit it.

Comment: @stivlo, I flagged it.

Comment: @stivlo - Why do the Ruby and Perl libraries share this tag?  See my earlier comment, and [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495034/ruby-url-parse-error) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495219/ruby-nethttp-start-issue).

Comment: @KevinVermeer I also don't like this, you're right. Is only 8 questions though, maybe we could kill the tag altogether and use networking. What do you suggest?

Comment: @squillman would be able to make a better judgement than I - I'm not involved in either community, and have no experience to even judge if such a tag is necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the tag for .Net questions is [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), while for network-related questions there is [networking](/questions/tagged/networking).

The questions tagged [net](/questions/tagged/net) should be retagged using one of the other tags. It needs to be manually done, as it is first needed to read the question to understand if it is a question about networks, or about .NET.
Once the questions are re-tagged, [net](/questions/tagged/net) could be made a synonym of [networking](/questions/tagged/networking), which already has [network](/questions/tagged/network) as synonym, or blacklisted to avoid it gets used from users that confuses it with [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) or [networking](/questions/tagged/networking) (as suggested by agf).

Comment: Or it could be blacklisted, so people have to choose either `.net` or `network*`.

Comment: I would like to see the .net tag blacklisted NOW, so it can be put on any new quesions, then the past mess can be sorted out over time.

Comment: @IanRingrose I think you cannot blacklist a tag if it is still used.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - You'd need to merge (but not make a synonym) with some new tag (such as [.net-version-independent]), then blacklist the .net tag.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think we should make [net](/questions/tagged/net) a synonym of anything, since new users probably won't pay attention and end up mistagging `.net` questions as `networking` (or vice-versa).  We need to burninate this tag now that it has been removed from all questions.

Comment: Burnination == removal from all questions.  It's just the automatic version, which works by deleting the tag.  In this case, editing was necessary to change the tag to .net, networking, or net-library.  Do you mean blacklist?

Comment: I consider Burnination = Blacklist w/ removal, so yeh with the removal done, we just need to blacklist it now.