# Encourage the creation of tag wikis/excerpts of popular (empty) tags being used for different purposes

Tags: feature-request, bounties, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

The question about [Make it impossible to create tags with no wiki description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152322/) contains multiple interesting viewpoints (answers) that all seem to make sense.

However, by allowing empty tags to be created (as is currently the case), chances are that such (empty) tag gets used in **2 (or more) completely different ways**. And the more popular such empty tag becomes, the more these chances go up (and the harder the retagging will become).

Before reading on, what would "you" expect a tag like ***guide*** (on SO) to be related to? Refer to my question about [Split [guide] into more specific tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290063) (from Apr 13, 2015) for an illustration of that tag, and how it was used for 2 completely different things. The tag excerpt was empty until my suggested edit for it got approved ([on Apr 14, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7685640)). For another example, refer to [The "net" tag is used for different purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108231).

**Note**: IMHO, none of the "Questions that may already have your answer" (which show up when creating this question) are to be considered as a duplicate, though some of them come close, such as [Promote tag wiki creation for new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the question about [Make it impossible to create tags with no wiki description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152322/), how about some compromise like so: continue empty tags to be created, but as soon as a tag becomes "popular" (= has at least X questions tagged with it), come up with some mechanisme to:

- somehow **feature** such tag, trying to get attention from somebody to have an excerpt (at least, maybe also for the tag wiki) created for such tag. So  somehow similar to [featured questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured).
- **grant an appropriate reward** (i.e. a rep increase of +Y, whereas 'Y' may or may not be equal to 'X' above ...). And this to the user actually creating such tag excerpt (at least, maybe also for the tag wiki). So somehow similar to being rewarded a bounty, though in this case I guess it'd be the system that should create such bounty-like incentive. It would be nice if it could be implemented as a user creating a bounty for such tag excerpt/wiki to be created ... Users with insufficient rep would still have to pass the wiki edit review process of course.

Here are some other questions which I believe are somehow related to this question, and which might be (partially) addressed by an approach like above also:

- [Searching for popular tags without tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152867): even though that question is more like "how can I find such tags", it would become easier to find such tags. Also note the "*It can help generate useful tag wikis where they are truly needed.*" in it.
- [Search all tags with no tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165889) (and also
  [Is there a way to find empty tag wikis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244930), which appears to be a duplicate of it).
- [Encourage tag wiki creation/edits by awarding more reputation to editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91739/).

PS: maybe something like a [tag-bounty](/questions/tagged/tag-bounty) should be considered as a relevant new 'tag' also?